# Modeling a rating system in Prisma

Tags: next.js, prisma

I want to include a rating system (like **YouTube** has it) in my project (using Next.js). How should I model the rating in `Prisma`-language?

I know this is a short question. It deserves a short answer.

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Can you describe the context in which you need the rating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a Prisma schema that would allow you to record ratings for movies and the associated user who rated the move:

```
model User {
  id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  email        String    @unique
  city         String
  name         String?
  ratingsGiven Ratings[]
}

model Movie {
  id      Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String    @unique
  year    DateTime
  Ratings Ratings[]
}

model Ratings {
  id      Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  rating  Decimal
  movie   Movie   @relation(fields: [movieId], references: [id])
  movieId Int
  user    User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId  Int
}
```

This uses a decimal to represent the rating. If you wanted to do something simpler, you could just have thumbs up and down fields on the `Movie` model which you increment on user clicks:

```
model Movie {
  id      Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name    String    @unique
  year    DateTime
  thumbsUp Int
  thumbsDown Int
}
```

With this simpler model, you could use the [atomic number operations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#atomic-number-operations) to increment and decrement:

```
const updatedMovie = await prisma.movie.update({
  where: { id: 10 }
  data: {
    thumbsUp: {
      increment: 1,
    },
  },
})
```